# How do I read a Python backtrace?

Tags: python, backtrace, xmp

I have a [Python script](http://pastebin.com/ES26YXPK) that copies pictures to a new directory (to remove duplicates) and tags them with [Python XMP Toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/python-xmp-toolkit/) which relies on the exempi library. After a random amount of time that can range between about a minute to 30 minutes, the script will crash with an error that, if I am reading the following "backtrace" right, comes from the libexmempi.so library. The first two lines are from my own script logging and the rest is from the backtrace.

```
2013-05-05 15:29:42,993 - dedupe_to_folder - DEBUG - TAG Products|Hearth
2013-05-05 15:29:42,993 - dedupe_to_folder - DEBUG - DESCRIPTION \\ourcomp-fs1\users\someuser\Documents\Pictures\By Product\Fireplaces\fireplace_0420.jpg
*** Error in `python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000a56fec6 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7fe66de80a46]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZNSt8_Rb_treeItSt4pairIKtN15PSIR_FileWriter16InternalRsrcInfoEESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessItESaIS4_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_E+0x64)[0x7fe66ca67454]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN15PSIR_FileWriter18DeleteExistingInfoEv+0x26)[0x7fe66ca66506]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN15PSIR_FileWriter20ParseMemoryResourcesEPKvjb+0x20)[0x7fe66ca667d0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN15PSIR_FileWriter21UpdateMemoryResourcesEPPv+0x295)[0x7fe66ca663a5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN16JPEG_MetaHandler9WriteFileEiRKSs+0x5a4)[0x7fe66ca321a4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN16JPEG_MetaHandler10UpdateFileEb+0x174)[0x7fe66ca319e4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN8XMPFiles9CloseFileEj+0xba)[0x7fe66ca24a7a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(WXMPFiles_CloseFile_1+0x41)[0x7fe66ca23641]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(_ZN9TXMPFilesISsE9CloseFileEj+0x18)[0x7fe66c9e9b68]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3(xmp_files_close+0x38)[0x7fe66c9e6d68]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c)[0x7fe66d2bbc18]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x190)[0x7fe66d2bb580]
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x4d1)[0x7fe66d4c8421]
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xabb6)[0x7fe66d4c8bb6]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xafd)[0x47c19d]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x19a)[0x4e09aa]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x994)[0x47c034]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x19a)[0x4e09aa]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x994)[0x47c034]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xcb7)[0x47c357]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x19a)[0x4e09aa]
python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x540412]
python[0x54088b]
python(PyRun_FileExFlags+0x92)[0x4658f6]
python(PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags+0x2d8)[0x465e26]
python(Py_Main+0xb4e)[0x466b9b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fe66de21ea5]
python[0x4e1635]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00639000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1835984                            /usr/bin/python2.7
00838000-00839000 r--p 00238000 fc:00 1835984                            /usr/bin/python2.7
00839000-008ae000 rw-p 00239000 fc:00 1835984                            /usr/bin/python2.7
008ae000-008c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
019f2000-0a5c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fe668ad4000-7fe6690d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe669790000-7fe6697a6000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625287                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe6697a6000-7fe6699a6000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 2625287                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe6699a6000-7fe6699a7000 r--p 00016000 fc:00 2625287                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe6699a7000-7fe6699a8000 rw-p 00017000 fc:00 2625287                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.17.so
7fe6699a8000-7fe6699aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe6699aa000-7fe6699b0000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625240                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7fe6699b0000-7fe669baf000 ---p 00006000 fc:00 2625240                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7fe669baf000-7fe669bb0000 r--p 00005000 fc:00 2625240                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7fe669bb0000-7fe669bb1000 rw-p 00006000 fc:00 2625240                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7fe669bb1000-7fe669bb3000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2621477                    /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fe669bb3000-7fe669db2000 ---p 00002000 fc:00 2621477                    /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fe669db2000-7fe669db3000 r--p 00001000 fc:00 2621477                    /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fe669db3000-7fe669db4000 rw-p 00002000 fc:00 2621477                    /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fe669db4000-7fe669dc6000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1842918                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fe669dc6000-7fe669fc6000 ---p 00012000 fc:00 1842918                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fe669fc6000-7fe669fc7000 r--p 00012000 fc:00 1842918                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fe669fc7000-7fe669fc8000 rw-p 00013000 fc:00 1842918                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fe669fc8000-7fe669fd7000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1843076                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7fe669fd7000-7fe66a1d7000 ---p 0000f000 fc:00 1843076                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7fe66a1d7000-7fe66a1d8000 r--p 0000f000 fc:00 1843076                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7fe66a1d8000-7fe66a1d9000 rw-p 00010000 fc:00 1843076                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7fe66a1d9000-7fe66a1dc000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625200                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
7fe66a1dc000-7fe66a3db000 ---p 00003000 fc:00 2625200                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
7fe66a3db000-7fe66a3dc000 r--p 00002000 fc:00 2625200                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
7fe66a3dc000-7fe66a3dd000 rw-p 00003000 fc:00 2625200                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
7fe66a3dd000-7fe66a492000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1842642                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.22.6
7fe66a492000-7fe66a691000 ---p 000b5000 fc:00 1842642                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.22.6
7fe66a691000-7fe66a697000 r--p 000b4000 fc:00 1842642                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.22.6
7fe66a697000-7fe66a698000 rw-p 000ba000 fc:00 1842642                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.22.6
7fe66a698000-7fe66a699000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66a699000-7fe66a713000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625196                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
7fe66a713000-7fe66a913000 ---p 0007a000 fc:00 2625196                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
7fe66a913000-7fe66a914000 r--p 0007a000 fc:00 2625196                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
7fe66a914000-7fe66a917000 rw-p 0007b000 fc:00 2625196                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
7fe66a917000-7fe66a928000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1843834                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1.0.0
7fe66a928000-7fe66ab27000 ---p 00011000 fc:00 1843834                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1.0.0
7fe66ab27000-7fe66ab28000 r--p 00010000 fc:00 1843834                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1.0.0
7fe66ab28000-7fe66ab29000 rw-p 00011000 fc:00 1843834                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1.0.0
7fe66ab29000-7fe66ab86000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 3301620                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
7fe66ab86000-7fe66ad86000 ---p 0005d000 fc:00 3301620                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
7fe66ad86000-7fe66ad89000 r--p 0005d000 fc:00 3301620                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
7fe66ad89000-7fe66ad8a000 rw-p 00060000 fc:00 3301620                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
7fe66ad8a000-7fe66ad8c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2100091                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
7fe66ad8c000-7fe66af8b000 ---p 00002000 fc:00 2100091                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
7fe66af8b000-7fe66af8c000 r--p 00001000 fc:00 2100091                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
7fe66af8c000-7fe66af8d000 rw-p 00002000 fc:00 2100091                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
7fe66af8d000-7fe66af99000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625242                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe66af99000-7fe66b198000 ---p 0000c000 fc:00 2625242                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe66b198000-7fe66b199000 r--p 0000b000 fc:00 2625242                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe66b199000-7fe66b19a000 rw-p 0000c000 fc:00 2625242                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so
7fe66b19a000-7fe66b1a5000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625246                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.17.so
7fe66b1a5000-7fe66b3a4000 ---p 0000b000 fc:00 2625246                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.17.so
7fe66b3a4000-7fe66b3a5000 r--p 0000a000 fc:00 2625246                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.17.so
7fe66b3a5000-7fe66b3a6000 rw-p 0000b000 fc:00 2625246                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.17.so
7fe66b3a6000-7fe66b3bd000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625236                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.17.so
7fe66b3bd000-7fe66b5bc000 ---p 00017000 fc:00 2625236                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.17.so
7fe66b5bc000-7fe66b5bd000 r--p 00016000 fc:00 2625236                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.17.so
7fe66b5bd000-7fe66b5be000 rw-p 00017000 fc:00 2625236                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.17.so
7fe66b5be000-7fe66b5c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66b5c0000-7fe66b5c8000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625238                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.17.so
7fe66b5c8000-7fe66b7c7000 ---p 00008000 fc:00 2625238                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.17.so
7fe66b7c7000-7fe66b7c8000 r--p 00007000 fc:00 2625238                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.17.so
7fe66b7c8000-7fe66b7c9000 rw-p 00008000 fc:00 2625238                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.17.so
7fe66b7c9000-7fe66b9ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66b9ca000-7fe66b9d3000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1842844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
7fe66b9d3000-7fe66bbd2000 ---p 00009000 fc:00 1842844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
7fe66bbd2000-7fe66bbd3000 r--p 00008000 fc:00 1842844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
7fe66bbd3000-7fe66bbd4000 rw-p 00009000 fc:00 1842844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
7fe66bbd4000-7fe66bc33000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1843723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7fe66bc33000-7fe66be32000 ---p 0005f000 fc:00 1843723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7fe66be32000-7fe66be33000 r--p 0005e000 fc:00 1843723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7fe66be33000-7fe66be3a000 rw-p 0005f000 fc:00 1843723                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1.0.0
7fe66be3a000-7fe66be3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66be3b000-7fe66be51000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2241740                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.so
7fe66be51000-7fe66c050000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 2241740                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.so
7fe66c050000-7fe66c052000 r--p 00015000 fc:00 2241740                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.so
7fe66c052000-7fe66c058000 rw-p 00017000 fc:00 2241740                    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.so
7fe66c058000-7fe66c06c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1970685                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66c06c000-7fe66c26b000 ---p 00014000 fc:00 1970685                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66c26b000-7fe66c26c000 r--p 00013000 fc:00 1970685                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66c26c000-7fe66c270000 rw-p 00014000 fc:00 1970685                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66c270000-7fe66c284000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625194                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe66c284000-7fe66c484000 ---p 00014000 fc:00 2625194                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe66c484000-7fe66c485000 r--p 00014000 fc:00 2625194                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe66c485000-7fe66c486000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 2625194                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fe66c486000-7fe66c56b000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1843068                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fe66c56b000-7fe66c76a000 ---p 000e5000 fc:00 1843068                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fe66c76a000-7fe66c772000 r--p 000e4000 fc:00 1843068                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fe66c772000-7fe66c774000 rw-p 000ec000 fc:00 1843068                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7fe66c774000-7fe66c789000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66c789000-7fe66c7af000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625189                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7fe66c7af000-7fe66c9af000 ---p 00026000 fc:00 2625189                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7fe66c9af000-7fe66c9b1000 r--p 00026000 fc:00 2625189                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7fe66c9b1000-7fe66c9b2000 rw-p 00028000 fc:00 2625189                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7fe66c9b2000-7fe66caad000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1842527                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3.2.2
7fe66caad000-7fe66ccad000 ---p 000fb000 fc:00 1842527                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3.2.2
7fe66ccad000-7fe66ccb3000 r--p 000fb000 fc:00 1842527                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3.2.2
7fe66ccb3000-7fe66ccb5000 rw-p 00101000 fc:00 1842527                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3.2.2
7fe66ccb5000-7fe66ccd6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ccd6000-7fe66ce87000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625179                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe66ce87000-7fe66d087000 ---p 001b1000 fc:00 2625179                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe66d087000-7fe66d0a2000 r--p 001b1000 fc:00 2625179                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe66d0a2000-7fe66d0ad000 rw-p 001cc000 fc:00 2625179                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7fe66d0ad000-7fe66d0b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66d0b1000-7fe66d0b4000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1970673                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d0b4000-7fe66d2b4000 ---p 00003000 fc:00 1970673                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d2b4000-7fe66d2b5000 r--p 00003000 fc:00 1970673                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d2b5000-7fe66d2b6000 rw-p 00004000 fc:00 1970673                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d2b6000-7fe66d2bd000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1842539                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe66d2bd000-7fe66d4bc000 ---p 00007000 fc:00 1842539                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe66d4bc000-7fe66d4bd000 r--p 00006000 fc:00 1842539                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe66d4bd000-7fe66d4be000 rw-p 00007000 fc:00 1842539                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.1
7fe66d4be000-7fe66d4da000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 1970668                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d4da000-7fe66d6d9000 ---p 0001c000 fc:00 1970668                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d6d9000-7fe66d6da000 r--p 0001b000 fc:00 1970668                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d6da000-7fe66d6de000 rw-p 0001c000 fc:00 1970668                    /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7fe66d6de000-7fe66d71f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66d71f000-7fe66de00000 r--p 00000000 fc:00 1841393                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fe66de00000-7fe66dfbe000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625169                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fe66dfbe000-7fe66e1bd000 ---p 001be000 fc:00 2625169                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fe66e1bd000-7fe66e1c1000 r--p 001bd000 fc:00 2625169                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fe66e1c1000-7fe66e1c3000 rw-p 001c1000 fc:00 2625169                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7fe66e1c3000-7fe66e1c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66e1c8000-7fe66e2cb000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625217                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fe66e2cb000-7fe66e4cb000 ---p 00103000 fc:00 2625217                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fe66e4cb000-7fe66e4cc000 r--p 00103000 fc:00 2625217                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fe66e4cc000-7fe66e4cd000 rw-p 00104000 fc:00 2625217                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7fe66e4cd000-7fe66e4e3000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625322                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7fe66e4e3000-7fe66e6e2000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 2625322                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7fe66e6e2000-7fe66e6e3000 r--p 00015000 fc:00 2625322                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7fe66e6e3000-7fe66e6e4000 rw-p 00016000 fc:00 2625322                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7fe66e6e4000-7fe66e6e6000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.17.so
7fe66e6e6000-7fe66e8e5000 ---p 00002000 fc:00 2625314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.17.so
7fe66e8e5000-7fe66e8e6000 r--p 00001000 fc:00 2625314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.17.so
7fe66e8e6000-7fe66e8e7000 rw-p 00002000 fc:00 2625314                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.17.so
7fe66e8e7000-7fe66e8ea000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625184                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7fe66e8ea000-7fe66eae9000 ---p 00003000 fc:00 2625184                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7fe66eae9000-7fe66eaea000 r--p 00002000 fc:00 2625184                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7fe66eaea000-7fe66eaeb000 rw-p 00003000 fc:00 2625184                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7fe66eaeb000-7fe66eb03000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7fe66eb03000-7fe66ed02000 ---p 00018000 fc:00 2625281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7fe66ed02000-7fe66ed03000 r--p 00017000 fc:00 2625281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7fe66ed03000-7fe66ed04000 rw-p 00018000 fc:00 2625281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so
7fe66ed04000-7fe66ed08000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ed08000-7fe66ed2b000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 2625145                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fe66ed99000-7fe66ee5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ee8d000-7fe66ef14000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ef1a000-7fe66ef1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ef1c000-7fe66ef23000 r--s 00000000 fc:00 2100147                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7fe66ef23000-7fe66ef24000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 7897090                    /SYSV790005f0 (deleted)
7fe66ef24000-7fe66ef25000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ef25000-7fe66ef26000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ef26000-7fe66ef2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fe66ef2a000-7fe66ef2b000 r--p 00022000 fc:00 2625145                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fe66ef2b000-7fe66ef2d000 rw-p 00023000 fc:00 2625145                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7ffff1a9b000-7ffff1ac0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff1bfe000-7ffff1c00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I keep having to restart the script (so much so that I wrote some logic to let it start where it left off). There are so many pictures though that I'm not nearly finished and I'm tired of baby-sitting this script. Based on the contents of this Backtrace message, is it possible to diagnose and correct the issues [my script](http://pastebin.com/ES26YXPK) is having?

Comment: are you asking if the python script itself can examine the backtrace and react to it?

Comment: Looks like a segfault to me.  What version of Python are you using, on what system, and what library?  (If it's third party, it's likely that you could file a bug against it.)

Comment: @RyanHaining I didn't think it was something I could react to, I just wanted to know which of the many libraries reported in the dump was causing the issue.

Makoto, Python 2.7.4 64-bit on Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop. I'm not sure who actually develops exempi because I don't seem to be able to find an official page for it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That stack trace is native, not Python.

Something in libexempi.so.3 has tried to free a block of memory that isn't currently allocated. `PSIR_FileWriter::DeleteExistingInfo()` calls `std::_Rb_tree<unsigned short, std::pair<unsigned short const, PSIR_FileWriter::InternalRsrcInfo>…>::_M_erase(…)`, which I'm guessing means that `PSIR_FileWriter` is trying to remove an element from a `std::map<unsigned short, PSIR_FileWriter::InternalRsrcInfo>`.

In any event, libexempi has crashed your process. You may have to take it up with the libexempi developers.

**Helpful hint:** You can figure out what those gobbledegook symbols mean, e.g.:

```
_ZNSt8_Rb_treeItSt4pairIKtN15PSIR_FileWriter16InternalRsrcInfoEESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessItESaIS4_EE8_M_eraseEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_E
_ZN15PSIR_FileWriter18DeleteExistingInfoEv
```

…by running c++filt and pasting the stack trace into it.

Comment: Thank you, Marcelo. Never been very good at C++ so this is very helpful information on dealing with future backtraces like this.